# Is there a grammar definition (e.g. EBNF) for MongoDB queries?

Tags: mongodb, parsing, grammar, ebnf

I would like to build a tool that involves parsing a MongoDB query AST from an input string. However, I've been unable to find any comprehensive grammar definition on the web.

There's [mnogodb-language-model](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-language-model) for example, but it is very outdated. It's grammar doesn't support unquoted expressions or regular expressions (in `/.../` notation), and its AST doesn't seem to include anything inside an `$expr` filter.

I would be happy with any up-to-date comprehensive description, (E)BNF, pegJS, ANTLR, etc. Does anybody know where I might find something like that? If it happens to include the aggregation pipeline syntax, that would be even better.

Comment: [Bison source file from the MongoDB repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/5bbadc66ed462aed3cc4f5635c5003da6171c25d/src/mongo/db/cst/grammar.yy). Happy code reading! If you run it through Bison with the `-v` option, you'll find the grammar with all the action code stripped out at the beginning of the `.output` file.